# problem when using scope and rotate with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, rotating, scoping

I wish to take this picture with tikz turning figure
[image]

generally this type of scheme does not ask me problem
and I wrote the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.02,y={(0,-1)}]

\node[circle,draw, minimum size=1em,label={O}](O) at (0,0){};
\node[circle,draw, minimum size=1em,label={left:A}](A) at (-100,160){};
\draw[black] (O) -| (A);
\begin{scope}[rotate=-15]

\node[circle,draw, minimum size=1em,red,label={below:C}](C) at (422,20){};
\draw[red] (O) -| (C);
%\draw (O) circle (422);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(A)}]
\node[circle,draw, minimum size=1em,blue,label={below:B}] (B) at (30:280){};
\draw[blue] (A) -- (B);
\draw[green] (B) -- (C);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

and I get the following picture

[image]

I do not understand

- Why the order `\draw (O)-| (C)`  at point C?
- Why have to put a negative angle to rotate while it is not necessary to get the point B?

I specify the problem

the following code shows more precisely the problem

I wish to place a node at coordinates (422.20)
following that is placed the first node by a displacement along x and along y or otherwise, the node is not in the same place in the inclined repere while in the coordinate (x, y), it n 'no problem!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.02,y={(0,-1)}]
\node[circle,draw, minimum size=1em,label={O}](O) at (0,0){};
\begin{scope}[rotate=-15]
%\node[circle,draw, minimum size=1em,red](C) at (422,20) {};
%
\draw (O) --(422,0) coordinate(D);
\path(D) --++(0,20) node[draw,circle,red,label={below:C2}](C2){};

\draw (O) -- (0,20) coordinate(E);
\path (E) --++(422,0)node[draw,rectangle,green,label={below:C3}](C3){};
\end{scope}

\draw (O) --(422,0) coordinate(D);
\path(D) --++(0,20) node[draw,circle,red,label={below:C2}](C2){};

\draw (O) -- (0,20) coordinate(E);
\path (E) --++(422,0)node[draw,rectangle,green,label={below:C3}](C3){};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

===========
I think I've identified the problem, it comes from the scale, scale = 1, no worries !!

Comment: Not sure I understand your questions... What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want understand why my picture is not correct, and how obtain the correct picture  
I do not want to draw it for me but understand the problem

Comment: Well, for example, the TikZ operator `-|` or `|-` is only vertical or horizontal. It doesn't work in diagonal. So even if you rotate it, it won't work as expected.

Comment: yet it seems correctly draw but the end is not in the right place

Comment: Do you want to draw a line that *ends* at that point, or do you simply want to draw a perpendicular line from C?

Comment: I want to draw the perpendicular line from the point O to point C as in the drawing above. I will then be able to vary the angle to draw the set in another position (both AB and BC segments to be calculated)